# Understanding std::condition_variable

Tags: c++

I refer to the accepted answer here: [Using std::conditional_variable to wait on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769934/using-stdconditional-variable-to-wait-on-a-condition) and in particular the code (copied):

```
struct gate {
  bool gate_open = false;
  mutable std::condition_variable cv;
  mutable std::mutex m;

  void open_gate() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    gate_open=true;
    cv.notify_all();
  }
  void wait_at_gate() const {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    cv.wait( lock, [this]{ return gate_open; } );
  }
};
```

I don't understand how this works as an event class. How exactly does the code inside the mutex in `open_gate` execute if something is already waiting via the `wait_at_gate` functions. I'm guessing it has something to do with the `std::condition_variable`.

Comment: The condition variable unlocks its acquired lock and waits to be signaled, hence `open_gate` may proceed.

Comment: OK, so when the cv unlocks it remains blocked un til the other thread sets the gate_open and then calls the notify_all. This then calls the cv.wait handler, which if true (which it will be), unblocks the cv.wait? This all correct?

Comment: Saying the same as @PasserBy, but in a little more detail:  the `cv.wait(lock,...)` call _unlocks_ the mutex, and then it waits to be notified, and then it re-locks the mutex before it returns.

Comment: I'll accept an answer that has a detailed sequence of operations in cluding the gate_open and notify_all.

Comment: Detailed sequence described: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable. Tutorial on posix condition variables: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since no one is going to post, here's my answer, helped by the comments and the following links (from which quoted text is from, which slight modification for readability):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all

It assumes two threads, one, named `OG`, calling `open_gate()` and the other, named `WG`, calling `wait_at_gate()`.

1) Both functions are protected with locks, it is a requirement that "any thread that intends to wait on `std::condition_variable`" acquires "a `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, on the same mutex as used to protect the shared variable".

2) If `OG` gets the lock first then it will open the gate before releasing the lock. `WG` then gets its lock, the gate is already opened. For this case since (from linked references):

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

then there is no wait.

3) If `WG` gets its lock first then its call to `cv.wait` "atomically releases the mutex and suspends the execution of the thread."

4) This allows `OG` to proceed, which then sets the shared flag. `WG` "will then be unblocked when `notify_all()` is executed" by `OG`.